# Функция на haskell

Tags: haskell, функциональное-программирование

Есть такой код, представляющий собой попытку описать объект робота:

```
robot (name, attack, hp) = \message -> message(name, attack, hp)

name (n, _, _) = n
attack (_, a, _) = a
hp (_, _, hp) = hp

getAttack aRobot = aRobot attack
getHP aRobot = aRobot hp
getName aRobot = aRobot name

setName aRobot newName = aRobot(\(n, a, h) -> robot(newName, a , h))
setAttack aRobot newAttack = aRobot(\(n, a, h) -> robot(n, newAttack , h))
setHP aRobot newHP = aRobot(\(n, a, h) -> robot(n, n , newHP))

printRobot aRobot = aRobot( \(n, a, h) -> n ++ " attack: " ++ (show a) ++ " hp: " ++ (show h) )

damage aRobot dmg = aRobot(\(n,a,h) -> robot(n,a, h - dmg))

fight aRobot defender = damage defender dmg
    where dmg = if getHP aRobot > 0
                then getAttack aRobot
                else 0

getAllHP aRobots = map getHP aRobots
```

Теперь мне нужно написать функцию которая возвращает кортеж из двух роботов после одного раунда, я делаю это так:

```
oneRoundFight aR1 aR2 = ( fight aR1 aR2, fight aR2 aR1 )
```

Появляется ошибка:

```
*Main> :l robot.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( robot.hs, interpreted )

robot.hs:27:48: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
        b2 ~ ((a2, b2, b1) -> t1) -> t1
      Expected type: ((a2, ((a2, b2, b1) -> t1) -> t1,
                       ((a2, b2, b1) -> t1) -> t1)
                      -> ((a2, b2, b1) -> t1) -> t1)
                     -> a1
        Actual type: ((a2, b2, b1) -> ((a2, b2, b1) -> t1) -> t1) -> a1
    * In the first argument of `fight', namely `aR2'
      In the expression: fight aR2 aR1
      In the expression: (fight aR1 aR2, fight aR2 aR1)
    * Relevant bindings include
        aR2 :: ((a2, b2, b1) -> ((a2, b2, b1) -> t1) -> t1) -> a1
          (bound at robot.hs:27:19)
        aR1 :: ((a, ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t, ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t)
                -> ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t)
               -> b1
          (bound at robot.hs:27:15)
        oneRoundFight :: (((a, ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t,
                            ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t)
                           -> ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t)
                          -> b1)
                         -> (((a2, b2, b1) -> ((a2, b2, b1) -> t1) -> t1) -> a1)
 -> (a1, b1)
          (bound at robot.hs:27:1)
   |
27 | oneRoundFight aR1 aR2 = ( fight aR1 aR2, fight aR2 aR1 )
   |                                                ^^^

robot.hs:27:52: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
        b ~ ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t
      Expected type: ((a, b, a1) -> ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t) -> b1
        Actual type: ((a, ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t, ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t)
                      -> ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t)
                     -> b1
    * In the second argument of `fight', namely `aR1'
      In the expression: fight aR2 aR1
      In the expression: (fight aR1 aR2, fight aR2 aR1)
    * Relevant bindings include
        aR2 :: ((a2, b2, b1) -> ((a2, b2, b1) -> t1) -> t1) -> a1
          (bound at robot.hs:27:19)
        aR1 :: ((a, ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t, ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t)
                -> ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t)
               -> b1
          (bound at robot.hs:27:15)
        oneRoundFight :: (((a, ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t,
                            ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t)
                           -> ((a, b, a1) -> t) -> t)
                          -> b1)
                         -> (((a2, b2, b1) -> ((a2, b2, b1) -> t1) -> t1) -> a1)
 -> (a1, b1)
          (bound at robot.hs:27:1)
   |
27 | oneRoundFight aR1 aR2 = ( fight aR1 aR2, fight aR2 aR1 )
   |                                                    ^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
Prelude>
```

Я не совсем понимаю что значит этот вывод, а конкретно `cannot construct the infinite type:`
При этом если поменять аргументы местами: `( fight aR1 aR2, fight aR1 aR2 )` то этой ошибки не возникает.

Объясните пожалуйста.

При этом функция `fight` написана и работает:

```
Prelude> :l robot.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( robot.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> aR1 = robot("r1", 8, 100)
*Main> aR2 = robot("r2", 4, 120)
*Main> aR2_damaged = fight aR1 aR2
*Main> aR1_damaged = fight aR2 aR1
*Main> printRobot aR1_damaged
"r1 attack: 8 hp: 96"
*Main> printRobot aR2_damaged
"r2 attack: 4 hp: 112"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы уверены. что для хранения хранения такого простого набора данных вам действительно нужен такой сложный тип данных (функция от функции от кортежа)?

Если да, то вам придется столкнуться с полиморфизмом высших рангов, и вряд ли это то, с чем вы сейчас захотите иметь дело.

Если нет, то все можно описать гораздо проще

```hs
data Robot = Robot { robotName :: String, robotAttack :: Int, robotHP :: Int } deriving Show

getAttack = robotAttack
getName = robotName
getHP = robotHP

setAttack aRobot newAttack = aRobot { robotAttack = newAttack }
setHP aRobot newHP = aRobot { robotHP = newHP }
setName aRobot newName = aRobot { robotName = newName }

printRobot aRobot =
  getName aRobot ++
  " attack: " ++ show (getAttack aRobot) ++
  " hp: " ++ show (getHP aRobot)

damage aRobot dmg = setHP aRobot (getHP aRobot - dmg)

fight aRobot defender = damage defender dmg
    where dmg = if getHP aRobot > 0
                then getAttack aRobot
                else 0

getAllHP aRobots = map getHP aRobots

oneRoundFight aR1 aR2 = (fight aR2 aR1, fight aR1 aR2)
```

```hs
GHCi> aR1 = Robot "r1" 8 100
GHCi> aR2 = Robot "r2" 4 120
GHCi> (aR1', aR2') = oneRoundFight aR1 aR2
GHCi> printRobot aR1'
"r1 attack: 8 hp: 96"
GHCi> printRobot aR2'
"r2 attack: 4 hp: 112"
```

#### "Без дополнительных сущностей"

```hs
oneRoundFight aR1 aR2 =
  aR1 $ \(n1, a1, h1) ->
    aR2 $ \(n2, a2, h2) ->
      (robot (n1, a1, h1 - dmg h2 a2), robot (n2, a2, h2 - dmg h1 a1))
  where dmg hp attack = if hp > 0 then attack else 0
```

```hs
GHCi> aR1 = robot ("r1", 8, 100)
GHCi> aR2 = robot ("r2", 4, 120)
GHCi> (aR1', aR2') = oneRoundFight aR1 aR2
GHCi> printRobot aR1'
"r1 attack: 8 hp: 96"
GHCi> printRobot aR2'
"r2 attack: 4 hp: 112"
```

Comment: Это пример из учебника Уилла Курта "Программируй на Haskell", там тоже говориться что эта задача решается проще с помощью системы типов, но мне бы хотелось разобраться именно с функциями и замыканиями не вводя дополнительный сущностей.

Comment: @Rikitikitavi Этот пример уже выжал из типа данных практически все возможности, дальше без полиморфизма второго ранга придется сильно выкручиваться. В частности, нельзя (или очень тяжело) будет использовать готовые функции `getHP`, `getAttack` и т.д. Обновил ответ.